# Auto Generating and Printing PDF Files From Markdown?

Tags: pdf, printing, automation, markdown

I'm looking for a way to automatically have my computer generate and print PDF files from a folder full of markdown files.

So, every morning at 5AM I'd want my computer look at my /markdown-files folder, create a bunch of PDFs to go into a /PDF-folder and also run the printer so the pages are waiting for me.

There are a couple of requirements that might make this a bit tricky:

1. The PDFs should have the file title at the top of each page
2. The page needs to be A4
3. The lines should be double spaced at least.

I used to use WKPDF to generate PDFs, but it no longer works on Yosemite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with Markdown.pl and htmldoc(1), both of which can be installed with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).  The basic flow for making a PDF is:

```
markdown foo.markdown | htmldoc --no-toc --no-title -f foo.pdf -
```

As for your filename-per-page, you coul incorporate echo to add it as an HTML element:

```
echo $(markdown foo.markdown) "<p>foo</p>" | htmldoc --no-toc --no-title -f foo.pdf -
```

And for printing, the lpr(1) command will send a file to your default printer.

Tying this altogether:

```
for filename in `ls *.markdown`;
do
    echo $(markdown "$filename") "<p>$filename</p>" | 
        htmldoc --no-toc --no-title -f "${filename}.pdf" -
    lpr "${filename}.pdf"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I've played with htmldoc and can see how to get it to do what I want, but you'll have to forgive me, because I'm not sure where to *put* that piece of code to actually have it run at a particular time.

Comment: Edit: Hazel to the rescue!

Comment: Great! I would have suggested a cronjob, but [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) is much friendlier.

Comment: There is still one problem: this loop just prints the first file over and over, not all the files once.  

    for filename in `ls *.md`;
        do
        echo $(markdown $filename) "<p>$filename</p>" | htmldoc --no-toc --no-title --fontspacing 3 --size a4 -f ${filename}.pdf -lpr ${filename}.pdf
 done

Comment: I think I just realized that this is my own dumb fault for having pipes in my file names.

Comment: That assessment of your filename character choices is correct.

Comment: I can see there is still a problem: instead of creating and printing 'my filename.pdf' it's trying to do 'my.pdf' and 'filename.pdf'

Comment: Put double quotes around `$filename` wherever it is used as an argument to a command to overcome this. It should then also work with pipes in the name.

Comment: Isn't this answer an example of ["you should never parse `ls` output"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)?

So instead of `\`ls *.markdown\`` should be just `*.markdown` (with a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) *).

PS Also, it's a better practice to use `$(command)` instead of backticks `\`command\``.

Comment: Attempting to install html doc on el capitan yields: htmldoc: This formula either does not compile or function as expected on OS X
versions newer than Yosemite due to an upstream incompatibility.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

Comment: @CGPGrey Yeah, building it from [source (left sidebar)](https://www.msweet.org/projects.php?Z1) fails…but changing a single line makes it work.  On line 1385, cast that 0 to a boolean: `cinfo.quantize_colors = (boolean)0;`.  Then with a `./configure && make`, it builds & runs for me (the output program is htmldoc/htmldoc)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses LaTeX to generate the PDF. If you have long-form text in the Markdown files and would like to optimize for typographic readability (and I suspect you do), LaTeX tends to do a much better job compared to HTML engines.

It uses `pandoc` as an intermediary between Markdown and LaTeX, and also produces the PDF for you.

#### Main script

```
#!/bin/bash

md-dir="MARKDOWN_DIRECTORY_HERE"
pdf-dir="PDF_DIRECTORY_HERE"

cd "${md-dir}"
for filename in *.md; do
    target-pdf="${pdf-dir}/${filename}.pdf"
    pandoc "${filename}" -t latex --latex-engine=xelatex -V geometry=a4paper -V fontsize=11pt -V listings -V header-includes="\usepackage{fancyhdr}\pagestyle{fancyplain}\cfoot{}\rhead{\thepage}\lhead{\texttt{\lstinline/${filename}/}}" -V header-includes="\linespread{2.0}" -o "${target-pdf}"
    echo "produced ${filename}.pdf"
    lpr "${target-pdf}"
done
```

#### Required setup

1. Get `pandoc` from Homebrew: `brew install pandoc`
2. Install the minimal version of LaTeX called [BasicTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html)

#### Testing if you got the setup correct

You should be able to run in a new Terminal window (with bash)

```
echo "test" | pandoc -t latex --latex-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf
```

and get a valid `test.pdf` document with just the word "test"

#### Customizations

There's a lot you can tweak with the LaTeX settings from the command line

1. tweak the line spacing by changing the `\linespread{2.0}` multiplier
2. adjust markings by replacing `geometry=a4paper` with `geometry=a4paper,left=XXmm,right=XXmm,top=XXmm,bottom=XXmm`
3. change font size by chaining `11pt` to either 10pt or 12pt, and everything should scale accordingly
4. change the main font by adding another argument to `pandoc`: `-V mainfont="NAME OF FONT"`. You can also set `monofont` this way.

Comment: It would be more maintainable to just `\input{my-template-file}` from the command line.

Comment: Very interesting.  I'll play around with the option.  Thank you.

Comment: Running the test yields: "pandoc: xelatex not found. xelatex is needed for pdf output."

Comment: Just want to make sure: this is *after* installing the BasicTeX package as described above, right? Are you able to run "xelatex" or "pdflatex" normally from the terminal?

Answer (score -1):

I have not used WKPDF, but its author suggests a method by which it can be made to work in Yosemite:  https://github.com/plessl/wkpdf/wiki/How-to-install-on-MacOS-10.10-Yosemite

Comment: RVM: command not found.

Answer (score -1):

You could use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org). It's not as straight forward as WKPDF for PDF generation since it has a wider range of features, but works fine.